# Zypper | Quietly install Solution 1 for glib2-devel package

Tags: sles, zypper

I want to install the package `glib2-devel` inside a sles15 SP4 docker container via some setup script.

The script is failing due to `zypper install -y glib2-devel` is not getting installed quietly. Here is the exception:

```
Problem: the to be installed glib2-devel-2.70.4-150400.1.5.aarch64 requires 'libglib-2_0-0 = 2.70.4', but this requirement cannot be provided
  not installable providers: libglib-2_0-0-2.70.4-150400.1.5.aarch64[SLE_BCI]
 Solution 1: downgrade of libglib-2_0-0-2.70.5-150400.3.3.1.aarch64 to libglib-2_0-0-2.70.4-150400.1.5.aarch64
 Solution 2: do not install glib2-devel-2.70.4-150400.1.5.aarch64
 Solution 3: break glib2-devel-2.70.4-150400.1.5.aarch64 by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/3/c/d/?] (c): c
```

The problem basically is that it's wants a solution from 1 to 3 but fails since the flag -y is provided (I guess) and hence select the cancel option c.

This results in failure for docker container.

Is there a way to select `Solution 1` during the quiet installation of the above pacakge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the script by first downgrading `libglib` with version 2.70.5 (which already existed) to version 2.70.4. For this I used `-f` flag.

```
zypper install -fy libglib-2_0-0-2.70.4-150400.1.5
```

and then installed `glib2-devel`

```
zypper install -y glib2-devel
```